# Redirect when session expires - [Magento]

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my store when a sessions expires an click in my account the user is redirect to login page, but i want change this to home.

So, if someone can help me i’m glad. I’ll keep trying to do this, if i found a way i’ll post here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I found the answer!

File: `app/code/core/mage/custoumer/model/session.php`

Line: 266

```
$action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN,
   Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrlParams() 
);
```

You just need change the constant `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN`

This is all!